# Sublime text и спец. символы

Tags: sublime-text, символы

В Dreamveawer'e можно было нажать & и он тут же предлагал список спецсимволов - их вид и написание (« - &laquo;)

Как добавить такой функционал в Sublime Text 3?

Answer (score 1):

Уже сама нашла решиение:

Ctrl+Shift+P, Preferences - Settings: User, добавляем строку (без &):

```
"word_separators": "./\\()\"'-:,.;<>~!@#$%^*|+=[]{}`~?"
```

Ctrl+Shift+P, Bro, Enter

В папке User создаем файл HTML.sublime-completions со следующим содержимым:

```
{
    "completions":
    [
        { "trigger": "&amp;", "contents": "&amp;" },
        { "trigger": "&bull;", "contents": "&bull;" },
        { "trigger": "&copy;", "contents": "&copy;" },
        { "trigger": "&laquo;", "contents": "&laquo;" },
        { "trigger": "&mdash;", "contents": "&mdash;" },
        { "trigger": "&nbsp;", "contents": "&nbsp;" },
        { "trigger": "&ndash;", "contents": "&ndash;" },
        { "trigger": "&raquo;", "contents": "&raquo;" }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Не работает. Проверьте — нигде ли не ошиблись. У себя я проверил — выполнил действия в точности по Вашей инструкции. Спасибо.